# Cannot boot up on mac dual boot mavericks-debian, question mark displayed

Tags: macos, dual-boot

I have a mbp late 2012 retina in wich I have installed **mavericks** and debian in dual boot with efi support. Well this morning I've done a repair in recovery mode on my mac and then I was no more able to boot. I have a blank folder with question mark inside displayed when I try to boot.
I've tryied in recovery mode to reinstall the os since i've  a recent backup on a hard drive, but it fails right after it downloaded the packages saying an error occurred. Same thing when I try to recover my backup, it fails. 
I suppose the repair somehow trashed the boot partition.
I have to say I have filevault enabled, I dont know if it changes anything.
How can I fix it? Considering that I've tryied all of the solutions on this answer [[Blinking question mark on folder on boot](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127062/blinking-question-mark-on-folder-on-boot]) which btw is about lion and it's not my case

Comment: The steps are the same no matter what version. Lion and later have the same playbook with different packages. Think of making a sundae with chocolate ice cream. You are asking about vanilla ice cream. The steps are the same save for one choice of package.

Comment: Well in fact it wasn't the same. Something missed for me. I couldn't resize partitions and when I tried to reinstall the system in recovery mode I had an error by the end. Same thing if I wanted to restore from a backup. It happened that I had to **erase** all partitions before reinstalling the system. This worked for me. Anyway I agree it's the same procedure, but the erasing part missing. I couldn't explain why I had to erase all before reinstalling, maybe because I have filevault enabled and Debian also was crypted.